Limit of expectation of function of stopping time
Let $\tau_{n}$ be a stopping time such that $P(\tau_{n} \rightarrow \infty) = 1$, and consider the following limit:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} E(e^{t\wedge \tau_{n}}f(X_{t\wedge \tau_{n}}))$$
Can I say that because $\tau_{n} \rightarrow \infty$,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} E(e^{t\wedge \tau_{n}}f(X_{t\wedge \tau_{n}})) = E(e^{t}f(X_{t}))$$
Without applying any theorem about changing expected value and limit?
